# How to create a scene like this: touch your screen, there will be a firstView, touch your screen again, the screen will show a second view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if (touch.tapCount == 1)
    {
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1.png"];
        imageView.image=image;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    } completion:nil];

 }

else if(touch.tapCount == 2)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"view2.png"];
        imageView.image=image;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    } completion:nil];

  }

}
```

this is my way, but the result is not what I want.
 You have to double-click, it will show the second view, I also use tap gesture, but it's same, too.

Comment: yes, it really worked, Thanks a lot! but if I have show a lot of view , will there  be easier way?

Comment: yes, there wil be at least 20 view which will be shown, so it will be a little bit confusing if i use too many  value global

Comment: is it fix view1.png , view2.png and so on ?

Comment: if it is fix then just global integer value and append it in string"view" and increase it with each tap count make sure you check that iimage is available or not

Comment: sorry , I misunderstand what you said. the image's name is different. but it doesn't matter. Actually, there is also a lable . every time you touch the screen, the label.text will change,too. so whether there any other way to count the touch

Comment: UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1.png"]; there "view1.png" is title of label ?

Comment: nope, I mean there are some lable and image on the view. I made it! so appreciate for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Bool value global

`@property(nonatomic) BOOL isFirstViewAdded`

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if (!self.firstViewAdded)
    {
   self.firstViewAdded = true;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1.png"];
    imageView.image=image;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
} completion:nil];

}

else if(self.firstViewAdded)
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"view2.png"];
    imageView.image=image;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
} completion:nil];

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can require tap gesture `numberOfTapsRequired` and `numberOfTouchesRequired`. In addition, 
`(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
will get any touch events, including UIButton touch events but tap gesture can't.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Tap gesture recogniser` properly to handle single and double tap.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapAction::)];
singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:_singleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapAction:)];
doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[singleTapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapGesture];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:_singleTap];


- (void)singleTapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1.png"];
        imageView.image=image;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    } completion:nil];

}

- (void)doubleTapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"view2.png"];
        imageView.image=image;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've already try your way , but I have to tap twice instantly ,then it will show the secondView

Comment: What I meat was not to to handle single and double tap. Every single tap will show different view

Comment: if that's the case use @PKT approach, only don't add imageview as subview again and again. add subview only one time, then change only the image for every touch.